# Invalid implicit conversion from int_const 0 to address requested

Tags: solidity, truffle

Invalid type for argument in a function call. Invalid implicit conversion from int_const 0 to address requested.

Comment: Attach the code here so we can debug. It's like going to auto-mechanic asking for fix without the car.

Comment: You probably need to cast 0 to an address via `address(0)`.